# Systemd: Fix ordering cycle when mounting an NTFS volume on a legacy raid array at boot time

Tags: systemd, mount, startup, raid, ntfs-3g

## Problem

I have what the `mdadm` man page calls a "legacy array", i.e. a raid array without superblocks. I finally managed to make systemd mount my data partitions within at boot time, but systemd throws a few errors about dependency ordering along the way. I would like to resolve the issues, so that systemd mounts my filesystems as specified in `/etc/fstab`, without running into problems.

---

(No, I do not regard suppressing systemd's output as a valid solution.)

## Details

It is a legacy array, which means the "normal" startup procedure (Debian Linux's, in this case) cannot automatically assemble it at boot time, which means mounting the partitions on this array must fail. The solution is to inject a command that assembles the array into the boot process.

To successfully assemble and use my array I have to (names redacted)

```
mdadm --build /dev/md0 --raid-devices=2 --level=0 /dev/sdh /dev/sdi
```

On this array I have to partitions I want to mount at boot time and using `mount -a`. To that end I created the following entries in `/etc/fstab` (names redacted)

```
UUID="abcdefgh" /mnt/a ntfs-3g defaults,auto 0 0
UUID="12345678" /mnt/b ntfs-3g defaults,auto 0 0
```

With these entries and after running the `mdadm` command, I get my desired results when I type `mount -a`.

I injected the raid assemble command by creating (end enabling) a systemd service unit:

```
[Unit]
Before=mnt-a.mount mnt-b.mount

[Service]
TYPE=oneshot
ExecStart=mdadm --build /dev/md0 --raid-devices=2 --level=0 /dev/sdh /dev/sdi

[Install]
WantedBy=local-fs-pre.target
```

While this does work, it also seems to create a dependency cycle in systemd, which creates error messages:

```
sysinit.target: Job apparmor.service/start deleted to break ordering cycle starting with sysinit.target/start
sysinit.target: Job local-fs.target/start deleted to break ordering cycle starting with sysinit.target/start
```

Apparently systemd recovers from this and I end up with my volumes mounted and a working OS. My guess is that by using `ntfs-3g` I implicitly use `apparmor` earlier in the boot process than it's available. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Are you sure that's a legacy array or is that just how you made it work in Linux (e.g. some kind of windows/bios fakeraid)? Any strong reasons not to get rid of it altogether and set up RAID properly instead?

Comment: It's complicated. It's an OCZ device and apparently each OCZ device works a little bit different than other OCZ devices. However, it definetly is something the device does and even though it shows up as two devices, they are not individual devices. Apparently I have one of the weirder models. I cannot set up a "proper" array. Well, I can, but it will immediately lose its superblock...

Comment: The interessting thing is, that the device shows up as a single(!) boot-device in the BIOS/EFI, so there is some sort of superblock. However, so far I have been unable to properly use it. This may be driver related, idk.